# Cannot start ZXing from adb shell

Tags: android, adb, zxing

I downloaded the latest Barcode Scanner (https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner4.5.apk&can=3&q=Barcode+Scanner) and installed it onto my device. Here it is:

```
shell@android:/ $ pm list packages -3
package:com.google.zxing.client.android
```

Yet, when I try to run it, the class cannot be found:

```
shell@android:/ $ am start -n com.google.zxing.client.android/.SCAN            
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.google.zxing.client.android/.SCAN }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.google.zxing.client.android/com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN} does not exist.
```

Am I using the correct class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the intent action with the class name. You can see from the [manifest](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml) that the activity's class is `.CaptureActivity`.